# Why isn't Guice finding my List<Interface> binding?

Tags: dependency-injection, guice, kotlin

I've got a interface with a couple of implementations:

```
interface PuNoManager {
    fun notifyUser(userId: Int)
}

class FcmManager
@Inject
constructor(val fcmClient: FcmClient) : PuNoManager {
    override fun notifyUser(userId: Int) { ...  }
}

class ApnsManager
@Inject
constructor(val apnsClient: ApnsClient) : PuNoManager {
    override fun notifyUser(userId: Int) { ...  }
}
```

Which are both bound in my `Module`, along with a `@Provides`-annotated method to get a `List<PuNoManager>`:

```
class PuNoModule: AbstractModule() {
    override fun configure() {
        bind(ApnsManager::class.java)
        bind(FcmManager::class.java)
    }

    @Provides
    fun puNoManagers(apnsManager: ApnsManager, fcmManager: FcmManager): List<PuNoManager> {
        return listOf(apnsManager, fcmManager)
    }
}
```

The problem arises when I have a class that needs the `List<PuNoManager>`—Guice complains that the type hasn't been bound:

```
Explicit bindings are required and java.util.List<? extends ...PuNoManager> is not explicitly bound.
  while locating java.util.List<? extends ...PuNoManager>
```

I know my Guice setup is working, as I previously had just the `ApnsManager` and am adding the second `PuNoManager`, `FcmManager`.  The problem stems from the dependent class requesting injection of `List<PuNoManager>` instead of just `ApnsManager`.

Comment: Try `@JvmSuppressWildcards List<PuNoManager>` or `MutableList<PuNoManager>`

Comment: Great workaround idea—the annotation didn't work, but changing the constructor to request a `MutableList<PuNoManager>` got the injection to work properly.  When I pull out the debugger in the `@Provides` method the `listOf()` creates an `ArrayList`, which is indeed a mutable list.

Comment: I think the annotation should be `List<@JvmSuppressWildcards PuNoManager>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`List<X>` in Kotlin is translated to `java.util.List<? extends X>` on the JVM. Apparently, Guice doesn't support injection of such values. To avoid the wildcard here, you can use a `MutableList<X>` instead, which translates to `java.util.List<X>`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I tried using `mutableListOf(impl1, impl2)`, but I still get the error: No implementation for List<? extends InterfaceName> was bound.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding [`@JvmSuppressWildcards`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-suppress-wildcards/index.html) to the module class.